# Using pound sign (#) in Laravel routing?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

Laravel has no problem routing the following URI:

```
$router->get('demo/toggle.html', function() {
  return View::make('ng.demo.toggle');
});
```

However, this one won't work for some reason.

```
$router->get('demo#/toggle.html', function() {
  return View::make('ng.demo.toggle');
});
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything behind the `hashtag (#)` isn't send to the server, so Laravel can't catch it when you enter it in the browser. This is where the error comes from, Laravel only gets `demo`. 
You can try this with an existing, working route. Just write

```
demo/toggle.html#some_gibberish   <<< will still take you to demo/toggle.html
```

I'm wondering why you are using `'..../toggle.html'` as getter, one of the benefits of (Laravel's) url rewriting is that this is avoidable. You could use only `toggle` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  The reason was I was trying to add .html route was because I was trying to add the mobile-angular-ui (http://mobileangularui.com/demo/) demo to my existing laravel project.  I know Angular should route requests on its own and shouldn't let the request hit the server, but I made a laravel route for the hell of it and noticed it still didn't work.  It turns out, mobile-angular-ui wasn't working due to the removal of the trailing / in laravel's .htaccess file.  Once I removed that, everything worked fine. Thanks a bunch!